# How to set php includes in 404 file

Tags: php, .htaccess, include

I have php includes on all my pages for the navigation bars, side bars, footers and such, including my 404 page to keep the theme the same throughout the website.

I set up `htaccess` and every non existing page displays the 404 page in the root. However when I try to access subfolders that don't exist, the 404 page stills displays as expected except the php include file is messed up since the path is according to the root folder.

Any solutions for this?

Comment: check if css style file is correctly added to 404 file.

Comment: Whenever you're including something, css, js or php, do it from the root directory of your web server. ./